# Condition for a conformal map to have an injective extension to the boundary

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $U$ be a bounded simply connected domain in the plane. Assume that $\partial U$ is locally connected, so that any conformal map $f : D \rightarrow U$ extends to a continuous map $  \bar D \rightarrow \bar U$, where $D$ is the unit disk.

It is known (Caratheodory's theorem) that $f$, thus extended, is injective (hence a homeomorphism) if and only if $\partial U$ has no cut points. Here, a cut point of a connected set $A$ is a point $x\in A$ such that $A\setminus \{x\}$ is not connected.

Now, suppose we know that $\mathbb C \setminus U$ (instead of $\partial U$) has no cut points. Can we still say that the extension of $f$ to $\bar D$ is injective? Equivalently, does knowing that $\mathbb C\setminus U$ has no cut points imply that $\partial U$ has no cut points?

Comment: For your question, do you still assume that $\partial U$ is locally connected?

Comment: Yes, I am still assuming that $\partial U$ is locally connected.